# Search by name and category cannot keep both parameters in the url in ASP MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I could not find any answer in the whole internet for this:

I am making a search by NAME. In addition, I provide some buttons of CATEGORY. The reason is, I want users to seach by name and narrow it by category. It works that way, but not the other way.

here is the detail, explained by the url (because this is what I am asking):

**scenario 1 (works perfectly):**

fresh page
=> l*calhost/Product/Index

search by name
=> l*calhost/Product/Index?searchTerm=machine

narrowing by a category actionlink after search by name
=> l*calhost/Product?searchTerm=machine&category=Soil

**SCenario 2 (here is the problem):**

fresh page
=> l*calhost/Product/Index

push a category button to list products under this category only
=> l*calhost/Product?category=Cement

insert a search term by name to look for the product as listed by the category as above
=> l*calhost/Product**?searchTerm=machine**

Instead of appending the **searchTerm=machine**, it replaces the **category=Cement** which were already in the url.

Please tell me how to fix this.

here is the controller:

```
//
    // GET: /Product/
    public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = null, string category = null)
    {
        ViewBag.SearchTerm = searchTerm;
        ViewBag.Category = category;

        var CategoryList = new List<string>();

        var CategoryQuery = from c in _db.Products
                            orderby c.Category.Name
                            select c.Category.Name;

        CategoryList.AddRange(CategoryQuery.Distinct());
        ViewBag.CategoryList = CategoryList;

        var products = from p in _db.Products
                       select p;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
        {
            products = products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchTerm));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
        {
            products = products.Where(p => p.Category.Name == category);
        }

        return View(products);
    }
```

And here is the view for search bar:

```
<form method="get">
      <input class="span5" id="appendedInputButton" type="text" placeholder="Search Blog" name="searchTerm">
      <button class="btn btn-primary sicon-search sicon-white" type="submit"><i>Search</i></button>
</form>
```

and here is the code for category buttons:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.CategoryList)
            {
                string name = item;
                string cssClass = "";

                if (ViewBag.Category == name)
                {
                    cssClass = "active";
                }

                <li>
                    @Html.ActionLink(name, "Index", new { searchTerm = ViewBag.SearchTerm, category = name }, new { @class = cssClass })
                </li>
            }
```

Comment: I'm not too sure but this probably would work if `searchTerm ` could be a nullable value. Another option is to overload `public ActionResult Index(string category = null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit your search bar form there is only one piece of data being posted - `searchTerm`. For your controller to use both `searchTerm` and `category` you'll need `category` on the form as well.

I suggest adding `category` as a hidden input and setting it to the value of category in the URL. That way it will be persisted.

I may get the syntax a little wrong, but it will be something like:

```
<form method="get">
      @Html.Hidden("category", @Request.QueryString["category"])
      <input class="span5" id="appendedInputButton" type="text" placeholder="Search Blog" name="searchTerm">
      <button class="btn btn-primary sicon-search sicon-white" type="submit"><i>Search</i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: God bless you Sir! When you somehow visit Indonesia, I would be delighted to assist you.